# FB share not showing in IE8

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

This code works fine in FireFox but in IE8 fbshare button not showing.

```
 <div style='float: left;'>
  <script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <a name='fb_share'></a>
 </div>
```

http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp6l

check above link

Comment: Do you get any javascript error? Check console?

Comment: no all works fine no javascript error

Comment: Have you checked console by pressing f12?

Comment: yeah i did. no errors of javascript

Comment: in IE its showing Object doesn't support this property or method in console file: fb.share

Answer (score 1):

I think this is deprecated, this has already be answered in these threads:

[FB Share button is not being displayed anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548493/fb-share-button-is-not-being-displayed-anymore)

[FB Share button Javascript error in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594442/fb-share-button-javascript-error-in-ie8)

Comment: i found this answers but then how it comes in firefox?

Comment: well, i tried your code and got nothing in firefox, for me it does not work in any browser, and i also don´t get any error or warning in the console...could be that some gfx are already in your cache, so it works in your browser...or plenty of other reasons :) - but usually it´s a cache problem if something shows up on one computer and on the other it doesn´t (with the same browser).

Comment: yeah, i see it there. but still, i would just go for the XFBML version (see other threads on stackoverflow).