# FB Share button Javascript error in IE8

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-8, share

I am getting a javascript error for the FB Share button only in IE8. This started after the old Share button was disabled and subsequently re-enabled (see [Facebook Share button: is it officially dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537996/facebook-share-button-is-it-officially-dead))

The error I am getting is:

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
FB.Share                                                    Line: 128
Code: 0                                                     Char: 188
URI: http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: i have this same issue right now....any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a slightly modified version of the answer in the link I gave originally:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" lang="en">
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID"; // appId must be valid
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <fb:share-button type="button" href="http://www.foobar.com"></fb:share-button>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it this way?

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=SHARE%20ME&p[summary]=SOME%20CONTENT&p[url]=http://www.google.com&p[images][0]=http://fakeurl.com/shareImage.gif
```

Breakdown:

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100` - **MAIN URL**
`&p[title]=SHARE%20ME` - **SHARE TITLE**
`&p[summary]=SOME%20CONTENT` - **SHARE PARAGRAPH**
`&p[url]=http://www.google.com` - **URL TO SHARE**
`&p[images][0]=http://fakeurl.com/shareImage.gif` - **SHARE IMAGE THUMBNAIL**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and **removing** the following line worked for me after hours of searching online.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that if you can set IE8 in protected mode by selecting Internet options -> Security ->Trusted Sites ->Enable Protected Mode, the page is working fine.