# facebook share popup (maybe iframe popup) on the site

Tags: jquery, facebook

what is the best way to have the facebook share button on the website. I want to share the link and add small image to this. Do I need any key or sth like that? I hope that not

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11538315/601466

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to make a request dialog

The Request Dialog sends a Request from one user (the sender) to one or more users (the recipients).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Answer (score 0):

You can use tfe following link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=458358780877780&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/
```

You just have to customize the caption,description,link, and so on to suite your needs.

Comment: what is app_id in this example ? I dont have any app_id

Comment: and what is redirect_uri, I dont have one as well

Comment: you should create new app through this link https://developers.facebook.com/apps
then get the app_id

Comment: The app id is easy to get. redirect_uri is the url, where the user will be redirected after he posts.

Comment: but I dont want to have any app on facebook I just want to have link on my site ...

Comment: Then use the following link: http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwhatismycar.com%2Fnews%2F230bhp-subaru-brz%2F