# Facebook sharer.php not deprecated anymore?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I read a while ago that the sharer.php script was being deprecated in favour of the "like" button.  I just headed over to developers.facebook.com and found [an article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/) explaining how to use the sharer.php.  Does this mean it's back?

Comment: this one is older, but still up to date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537996/facebook-share-button-is-it-officially-dead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean its back?

Yes, it is.

The re-introduced it together with the new native share dialogs for iOS/Android apps:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/07/11/four-reasons-to-upgrade-to-the-new-share-dialog-for-ios/

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/08/20/new-tools-for-android-developers--updated-sdk--share-dialog-and-more/

Answer (score 3):

Yes the sharer.php is back and here are official examples on how to use it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/

One main advantages of using the sharer.php is that you can have big images in your posts.

If you follow the guide at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/ and use the javascript FB.ui dialog, you will never get big images.
The only way to get big images in your post is to use the sharer.php.