# How to track when a user completes a post using Facebook's older "share dialog" (sharer.php)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

I have a Facebook "share" button on my site, and for various technical reasons I've decided to use Facebook's older [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/), instead of their newer Javascript API. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537996/facebook-share-button-is-it-officially-dead) for a discussion of the difference; the way I'm using just opens up "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URL" in a new window.)

Anyway, I'm trying to send a tracking event to Google Analytics when the user completes a Facebook share, which Google has [pretty good docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial#facebook) explaining how to do. But the suggested method doesn't work for me, and I think it's because I'm not using the Facebook Javascript API directly for sharing. Here's what Google Analytics suggests doing:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('message.send', function(targetUrl) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'send', targetUrl]);
});
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to track facebook shares, using the older `sharer.php` share dialog?

Comment: I have same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Katie nope, had to work around it.